# Rails belongs_to/has_many with external Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.2

In my Rails 5.2 application I want to reference another Model. I have the following setup in the application:

```
class SomeModule::AnotherModule::User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :phones
end

class Phone < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, optional: true, class_name: '::SomeModule::AnotherModule::User'
end
```

The migration was done like so:

```
add_reference :phones, :user, foreign_key: true, index: true
```

Now, when I try to call upon the user from a phone I get this:

```
Phone.first.user
#=> NameError: uninitialized constant User::Phone
from /home/testuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:196:in `compute_type'
```

Removing the `class_name:` attribute does not change anything.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `has_many :phones, class_name: 'Phone'`

Comment: @JagdeepSingh Doesn't make any difference

Comment: @Severin Use `foreign_key: 'user_id'` , lets try the given solution below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class SomeModule::AnotherModule::User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :phones, class_name: 'Phone', foreign_key: 'user_id'
end

class Phone < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, optional: true, class_name: 'SomeModule::AnotherModule::User', foreign_key: 'user_id'
end
```